# Do I have to add all the frameworks I'm using in my app for ios8?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

The app is running in both simulator and my phone without any frameworks added in the "build phases".
Do I have to add the frameworks before uploading to Apple?
Thanks a lot.

The language I used is swift. and it's working in xcode 6 beta 3.

Comment: That doesn't make alot of sense; if you are not linking in frameworks then I would assume your app isn't actually using those frameworks.

Comment: Since version 5, Xcode has a build setting "Link Frameworks Automatically", which is by default on. You don't have to do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it automatically links anything you import, but make sure you `import Foundation`. I learned the hard way that things break weirdly (and intermittently) if you don't do this. Probably best to put it in your app delegate

Comment: Thanks! Hope that will secure it.